# Wpf и горячие клавиши

Tags: c#, wpf, hotkeys

Подскажите способ задания хоткеев с возможностью перенастройки. Настройки будут храниться в БД. В какую сторону копнуть?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тот же код на C# выглядит так:

```
window.InputBindings.Add(
        new InputBinding(ApplicationCommands.Open,
                         new KeyGesture(Key.R, ModifierKeys.Control)));
```

Вам понадобится, вероятно, поменять команду `ApplicationCommands.Open` на другую, и зарегистрировать для неё свой обработчик:

```
window.CommandBindings.Add(
        new CommandBinding(ApplicationCommands.Open, // или другая команда
                           DoOpen, CanOpen));
```

Комбинацию клавиш тоже можно поменять с `Ctrl-R` на ту, что прописана в вашей базе.

Answer (score 2):

Посмотри KeyBinding.

```
<Window.InputBindings>
  <KeyBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Open"
              Gesture="CTRL+R" />
</Window.InputBindings>
```

[вот это](http://msdn.microsoft.com/RU-RU/library/ms617169(v=VS.110,d=hv.2).aspx)

Comment: +1, но для возможности перенастройки не обойтись без code behind.

Comment: Да, хотелось бы как раз с перенастройкой